# 0 download or upload speed in wifi or ethernet connection in Kubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu, internet, ethernet

I am trying out Kubuntu 22.10 for a couple of weeks. It was working fine before but since the day before yesterday any network connection I make has no download or upload speed. I have ruled out any hardware or router problems as the Ubuntu System in the same device is working completely fine.(I have a dual-boot setup). I have tried looking through the forums but haven't found anything that has worked for me. I have tried disabling the firewall but that hasn't worked either. It can connect to the router administrator page but it can't connect to any other page.
I don't know if it would help but this is the output for `lshw -c Network`

```
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: 28:39:26:25:64:ef
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8821ce driverversion=5.19.0-28-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.102 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:141 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a4300000-a430ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 10
       serial: e8:6a:64:e1:db:e1
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-28-generic firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4204000-a4204fff memory:a4200000-a4203fff
```

This is the output for `iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Shitdroid"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 58:D9:D5:53:A8:D8
          Bit Rate=39 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-24 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:7   Missed beacon:0

lxcbr0    no wireless extensions.
```

This is the output for  `ifconfig`

```
enp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether e8:6a:64:e1:db:e1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 51208  bytes 4477590 (4.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 51208  bytes 4477590 (4.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lxcbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.3.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.3.255
        ether 00:16:3e:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::2a39:26ff:fe25:64ef  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 28:39:26:25:64:ef  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 27  bytes 3374 (3.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 61  bytes 13406 (13.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

this is the output from `route`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
10.0.3.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lxcbr0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 lxcbr0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0
```

All of the outputs were taken when connected to wifi.
I have checked the driver using `lsmod` and the driver `rtw88_8821ce` appears in the list.
I am sorry if it is a noob problem but any help would be very very apprecieated.